# Looking for the way to read a sentence containing a conjunction and a plural

Tags: grammatical-number, meaning-in-context

How does grammar tell me to parse this sentence:

*Visualize the relation between two-dimensional and three-dimensional objects.*

Are we being asked to visualize the relation between two-dimensional objects and also visualize the relation between three-dimensional objects (each dimension on its own)?

Or, are we being asked to visualize the relation between an object in the two-dimensional group and one in the three-dimensional group?

I think what's confusing me is the interaction between the plural *objects* and *and*. So, my question essentially is how to understand this sentence and similar ones having the same construct. Is there a grammatical rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed some ambiguity here, as you point out.

The most common and likely interpretation would be that the relation concerns the 2-d and 3-d objects mentioned in that sentence, and not a 3rd object - the context would probably help clarify though.

The other valid interpretation, which you proposed (involving a 3rd unmentioned object) would ideally be written by the author in a clearer way, such as:

> Visualize the relation between two-dimensional and between three-dimensional objects.

(i.e. two uses of `between`.)

Answer (score 1):

> Visualize the relation between two-dimensional and three-dimensional objects.

The phrasing is ambiguous, but I would say you are being asked to compare class characteristics of a two-dimensional object versus those of a three-dimensional object.

Answer (score 0):

I read that sentence as:

> Visualize the global set of objects that are 2-d with the global set of objects that are 3-d.

Compare the sets themselves to eachother, not the specific objects within the sets with other specific objects.